# Query compilation and provisioning times

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What does it mean there is a longer time for COMPILATION_TIME, QUEUED_PROVISIONING_TIME or both more than usual?
I have a query runs every couple of minutes and it usually takes less than 200 milliseconds for compilation and 0 for provisioning. There are 2 instances in the last couple of days the values are more than 4000 for compilation and more than 100000 for provisioning.

Is that mean warehouse was being resumed and there was a hiccup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COMPILATION_TIME:

The SQL is parsed and simplified, and the tables meta data is loaded. Thus a compile for `select a,b,c from table_name` will be fractally faster than `select * from table_name` because the meta data is not needed from every partition to know the final shape.

Super fragmented tables, can give poor compile performance as there is more meta data to load. Fragmentation comes from many small writes/deletes/updates.

Doing very large INSERT statements can give horrible compile performance. We did a lift-and-shift and did all data loading via INSERT, just avoid..

PRIOVISIONING_TIME is the amount of time to setup the hardware, this occurs for two main reasons ,you are turning on 3X, 4X, 5X, 6X servers and it can take minutes just to allocate those volume of servers.

Or there is failure, sometime around releases there can be a little instability, where a query fails on the "new" release, and query is rolled back to older instances, which you would see in the profile as `1, 1001`. But sometimes there has been problems in the provisioning infrastructure (I not seen it for a few years, but am not monitoring for it presently).

But I would think you will mostly see this on a on going basis for the first reason.

Comment: Thanks for explaining both. But my question was around like what could be the reason for seeing a huge difference for compilation and provisioning times given that the SQL is same all the time and ran more than 200,000 so far.

Comment: Yes. I see i would have mentioned things that explain a be  that would not apply. Please ignore those parts. Which probably mean you just wanted a “ yes” hiccup question.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation process involves query parsing, semantic checks, query rewrite components, reading object metadata, table pruning, evaluating certain heuristics such as filter push-downs, plan generations based upon the cost-based optimization, etc., which totally accounts for the COMPILATION_TIME.

QUEUED_PROVISIONING_TIME refers to Time (in milliseconds) spent in the warehouse queue, waiting for the warehouse compute resources to provision, due to warehouse creation, resume, or resize.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html

To understand the reason behind the query taking long time recently in detail, the query ID needs to be analysed. You can raise a support case to Snowflake support with the problematic query ID to have the details checked.